# Can I take $n(\epsilon)$ to be this value?

Tags: limits, solution-verification

> Prove that $\displaylines{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{3n+2}{2n+7}=\frac{3}{2}}$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then

$\begin{aligned} \left | \frac{3n+2}{2n+7}-\frac{3}{2} \right |=\left | \frac{6n+4-6n-21}{2(2n+7)} \right |=\left | \frac{-17}{2(2n+7)}\right |=\left | \frac{-17}{2(2n+7)}\right |=\frac{17}{4n+14}&<\frac{17}{4n}<\epsilon\\ &\Rightarrow n>\frac{17}{4\epsilon} \end{aligned}$.

Take $n(\epsilon)=\left \lceil \frac{17}{4\epsilon} \right \rceil\in \mathbb{N}$. Is this correct or not?

Comment: It is correct for me.

Comment: Your choice of $n(\epsilon)$ is valid. However, writing $\Rightarrow n>\frac {17}{4\epsilon}$ is logically wrong. -- What I mean is: The inequality $\left|\frac{3n+1}{3n+7}-\frac32\right|<\frac{17}{4n}$ does **not** imply that $n>\frac{17}{4n}$. Rather, it implies that **if** we ensure that $n>\frac{17}{4n}$, for example, by ensuring that $n\ge n(\epsilon):=\left\lceil\frac{17}{4\epsilon}\right\rceil$, **then** $\left|\frac{3n+1}{3n+7}-\frac32\right|<\epsilon$.